# How can I force the bootstrap datepicker display the value of the input field in the calendar?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar, bootstrap-modal

I have a strange problem with the bootstrap datepicker (I use it inside a bootstrap modal).

If I set the value directly in the input field...

```
<input value="12.05.2017" type="text" class="date">
```

... the datepicker is working well. This means, if I click on the input field, the datepicker displays the correct date inside the calendar:

[image]

But if I set the value via jquery..

```
<input value="" type="text" class="date">

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open_modal", function () {
  $(".date").val("11.06.2017");
}
</script>
```

... then, if I click on the input field, the calendar is opening, but not displaying any date:

[image]

What could cause this problem?

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/2510/

Comment: can you share link of datepicker you are using ?

Comment: a fiddle would be nice :)

Comment: Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/2510/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the [datepicker methods](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update):

```
$('.open_modal').click(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker('update', new Date(2017, 6, 11));
});
```

### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/2512/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.open_modal').click(function() {
$('.date').datepicker('update', '11.06.2017');
});
```

Datepicker gets the initial value from input, if any, and initalize with it. But after initializing the datepicker on the input, you should use datepicker api to change the value.

And one more thing. Your date format doesn't fit with the value you provide:

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
     dateFormat: '**dd-mm-yy**',
     minDate: '+5d',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     altField: "#idTourDateDetailsHidden",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });
```